# How to create a for loop from a input dependent function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, web-scraping, telethon

I am finally getting the hang of Python and have started using it on a daily basis at work. However, the learning curve is still steep and I have hit a roadblock in trying something new with a code I found [here](https://python.gotrained.com/scraping-telegram-group-members-python-telethon/) for scraping members from telegram channels.

Currently in lines 38-44 we can select a group from the list and it will scrape the user data into members.csv .

**EDIT**: Resolved the CSV naming issue:

```
    print('Saving In file...')
    print(target_group.title)
    filename = target_group.title 
    with open(("{}.csv".format(filename)),"w",encoding='UTF-8') as f:
```

Instead of relying on input, I would like to create a for loop which would iterate through every group in the list.

```
print('Choose a group to scrape members from:')
i=0
for g in groups:
    print(str(i) + '- ' + g.title)
    i+=1 
g_index = input("Enter a Number: ")
target_group=groups[int(g_index)]
```

The problem is that I am not sure exactly how to replace this part of the code with a for loop.

Although, just changing it into a for loop would make it merely overwrite the same members.csv file with each iteration, I plan on changing that so that it outputs into unique files.

So circling back to my question. How do I make this single program iteration loop through all of the groups, or just select all of them.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up figuring out the issue:

**On naming the CSV file**: Used the title attribute to name the file and replacement within the string.

```
g_index = chat_num
target_group=groups[int(g_index)]
filename = target_group.title 
print('Fetching Members from {} ...'.format(filename))
all_participants = []
all_participants = client.get_participants(target_group, aggressive=True)

print('Saving In file...')
with open(("{}.csv".format(filename)),"w",encoding='UTF-8') as f:
```

**On creating a for loop for the sequence:** The original code (posted in the question) did not include a for loop. My version of a workaround was to create a function from everything and then iterate through a an indexed list that was equal to the amount of instances detected. In the end looking like this:

```
chat_list_index = list(range(len(chats)))

for x in chat_list_index:
    try: 
        get(x)
    except:
        print("No more groups.", end = " ")
        pass
    pass
print("Done")
```

Overall, this might not be the best solution to accomplish what I sought out to, however its good enough for me now, and I have learned a lot. Maybe someone in the future finds this beneficial. Full code available here: (https://github.com/ivanstruk/telegram-member-scraper/).

Cheers !

Comment: You can remove the two `pass` here, they are not needed since the `for` and the `except` are not empty scopes.

Comment: Thanks ! That makes sense !

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't test this, but something like this maybe? This creates a new .csv file for each group.

```
for chat in chats:
    try:
        if chat.megagroup == True:
            groups.append(chat)
    except:
        continue

for current_group in groups:

    print(f"Fetching members for group \"{current_group.title}\"...")
    all_participants = client.get_participants(current_group, aggressive=True)

    current_file_name = f"members_{current_group.title}.csv"

    print(f"Saving in file \"{current_file_name}\"...")
    with open(current_file_name, "w+", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=",", lineterminator="\n")
        writer.writerow(["username", "user id", "access hash", "name", "group", "group id"])
        for user in all_participants:
            username = user.username if user.username else ""
            first_name = user.first_name.strip() if user.first_name else ""
            last_name = user.last_name.strip() if user.last_name else ""
            name = f"{first_name} {last_name}"
            row = [username, user.id, user.access_hash, name, current_group.title, current_group.id]
            writer.writerow(row)
    print(f"Finished writing to file \"{current_file_name}\".")
print("Members scraped successfully.")
```

Comment: Thanks for the input ! I tried it, but it did not work. I was able to solve the CSV naming issue simply with the following fix:

'''
    print('Saving In file...')
    print(target_group.title)
    filename = target_group.title 
    with open(("{}.csv".format(filename)),"w",encoding='UTF-8') as f:
'''

Comment: Now I am trying to figure out a way for it to loop through every single target group.

Comment: Sorry about that, just added a fix to my original post (I was treating current_group like it was a string in certain parts, oops). Let me know if it works now.